# get check box value dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

we have list employees with email id using below code

```
<tbody>
<?php 
$sqlquery = mysql_query("select * FROM employee");
while($row=mysql_fetch_object($sqlquery)){                                  
?>  
<tr class="gradeA">
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="eid" value="<?php echo $row->emailid;?>" onclick="send_email_form_test()"><?php echo $row->name;?></td>
</tr>   
<?php }?>
</tbody>
```

when checkbox is clicked following function call,

```
 function send_email_form_test(){
var selected = new Array();     
$("input:checkbox[name=eid]:checked").each(function() { 
if($(this).val() !=""){
selected.push($(this).val());
}       
});

alert(selected.join(','));
var final_email = selected.join(',');
document.getElementById("to").value =final_email;
}
```

after click the checkbox,email ids are appears in "to" textarea field .when i will go to second page of the employee list, i cant able to get "to" textarea field,it will empty on the second page

```
   <div>
<label for="required">TO</label>
<textarea name="to"  cols="5" rows="10"></textarea> 
</div>

<div>
<label for="email">Subject</label>
<input type="text"  size="80" id="subject" name="subject" >
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</div>
```

how to add and remove the email ids with comma separated,when i click the checkbox.I have issue on when i will go on next page of the pagination

Comment: Using onclick on checkbox will execute function whether it's checked or unchecked. Add a button at the end with onclick assigned. Also, name the checkboxes `name="eid[]"`

Comment: If you use PHP paginator, you would either need to download the pages via AJAX and page them locally, or use AJAX to send selected emails to server before switching the page. You can't store something locally on page when your PHP generates new page with every click.

Answer (score 0):

You can add 'this' parameter to the Javascript function as onclick="send_email_form_test(this)"> then you will get the clicked checkbox object. Then you will be able to retrieve the value of the clicked check box

Answer (score 0):

I did not test it, but I think this is how you could collect emails from all pages

```
<?php
    //...
    echo '<script>window.tablePage = ', $paginator->currentPage, ';</script>';
 ?>

<script type="application/javascript">
 //...
 pageSelected = selected.join(',');

 //get emails selected on other pages
 allSelected = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('emails'));

 //add currently selected emails
 allSelected[tablePage] = pageSelected;
 localStorage.setItem('emails', JSON.stringify(allSelected));

 //output emails from all pages
 document.getElementById("to").value = allSelected.join(',');
 //...
</script>
```

(JSON library is here: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js )